# What is the trade of an electrician called?

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology, hypernyms

For example, a carpenter works in carpentry and a plumber works in plumbing. So what trade does an electrician work in? Electrical?

I searched the definition for "electrical" and found that it gives the part of speech as an adjective and not a noun like the dictionary does with carpentry or plumbing.

This is confusing to me.

I would like to understand and know how to talk about the trade for an electrician.

I would appreciate it if someone could help clarify and explain this to me.

Comment: It isn't often but if it were, would it not be 'electrics'?

Answer (score 17):

It is called **electrical work** (or you could use **electrical trade**). It is a noun phrase as the adjective *electrical* modifies the noun *work*. There isn't a single word noun for the trade of an electrician. Electricians were originally scientists concerned with electricity but this sense is very rare now.

Here is a usage from [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrician)'s "Electrician" article:

> Many jurisdictions have regulatory restrictions concerning electrical work for safety reasons due to the many hazards of working with electricity.

Comment: Yes, there is no  term like "carpentry" that refers to the electrician's trade.

Comment: @TimR although it's not like a new coinage like "electricianry" wouldn't be understood (assuming it was heard clearly)

Comment: I've heard "electrics" being used as well. "He works in electrics" or "He came to work on my electrics".

Comment: @An_Elephant   Not sure what you meant.

Comment: @Tristan  And after the electricianry has been completed, we can send the message  "What hath God wrought".

Comment: +1 As a former member of the IBEW, 'electrical work' is appropriate and widely used. Electrical work would be in distinction to electrical engineering, which is more technical and academic. IBEW literally represents 'electrical workers' which includes both high and low-voltage electricians. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Brotherhood_of_Electrical_Workers -> "The union also represents some workers in the computer, telecommunications, and broadcasting industries, and other fields related to electrical work."

Comment: @DJClayworth _Electrics_ is normally used for electrical parts or system, and it can include wiring. Perhaps, usages like "He works in electrics" is non-standard colloquial or it is short for "electrics field". I don't think it would refer to the electrician's trade.

Comment: Isn't "electrics" more or less specific to British English? I rarely hear it in American English.

Comment: It seems "electrical engineering" is these days used quite loosely in a lot of contexts, as an alternative to "electronics" to distinguish from the new meaning of "electronics" as in "consumer electronic devices"

Answer (score 10):

It may seem odd (or it may just be because electrician work is relatively new as a profession compared to the others), but electricians do **electrical** (or *electrical work*, which is probably more common than the standalone noun). For example, there is a "Carpentry, Electrical, Plumbing and Masonry" program at [Newton College and Career Academy](https://ncca.newtoncountyschools.org/career_clusters/architecture_and_construction/carpentry__electrical__plumbing_and_masonry). This is used outside of titles, such as in the news article [Surveillance cameras help capture holiday thieves](https://www.wwlp.com/news/surveillance-cameras-help-capture-holiday-thieves/):

> “There’s all different types of cameras out there,” says Ken Green who works in electrical at Lowe’s in Waterford [Connecticut] where home security is DIY do it yourself.

And here's another example as a noun, referring to a project where electrical work needs to be done: [When the floor/tile guy says, “he can do the electrical” this is what he might mean](https://www.reddit.com/r/electricians/comments/rgqky7/when_the_floortile_guy_says_he_can_do_the/).

The dictionary may not explain this usage, but it is idiomatic.

Comment: I think colleges use "electrical" in titles as a short form of "electrical studies/classes/professions" etc. It is not meant as a noun for an electrician's trade. _Electrical_ in "He can do the electrical" is meant for a specific electrical work involved but not the electrical trade. I don't think "He works in electrical." works.  I've never heard of it and Google has a very few results for "works in electrical at". Department stores use "electrical" as a short form. Also, "works in electrical at < somewhere >" appears to have a different isolated sense than working in electrical trade.

Comment: _OED_ lists a noun sense of "electrical" (plural, chiefly British) as "Electrical appliances or circuitry.".

Comment: I've also found a few usages from users in Reddit, LinkedIn etc. as "worked in electrical for < x number of years >". Is it idiomatic in some regions perhaps? Or some electricians adopted "electrical" as a short form to define their work or "electrical field"?

Comment: @ermanen All of the examples I found seem to be from the US, so it's possible (or just a coincidence).

Comment: As in the standaloning of 'nuclear' in 'we need a mix of coal, gas, electric and nuclear'.

Comment: By the way, I'm okay if this answer is accepted. I had no idea people use "electrical" in this sense.

Comment: For some reason, *eletricry* didn't quite make it. https://i.ebayimg.com/images/g/p90AAOSwCgpkv9gV/s-l1600.jpg

Comment: @ermanen When the comments lead to someone (even—or especially—me) editing to make a better answer, I think it's all good :)

Comment: 'That’s a[n electrical corridor]. It’s impossible, no one can pilot [electrical].' – Matrix II ('mechanical')

Comment: I would say that the plural "electricals" sounds most natural because it's actually a noun whereas "electrical" is not.

Comment: @DKNguyen That's [something else](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/electricals). In this case I'm talking about, *electrical* is some sort of mass noun, so it doesn't take the plural.

Answer (score 4):

The word you're looking for is "electrics".

However, it's not often used in this context. Most people would say "electrical work".

It's also worth noting that if you modify the type of work to be on electrical devices (say phones, computers, etc.), rather than power delivery, you'd typically refer to that as "electronics".

Comment: "Electrics" is reasonably common in Britain but so is "Electrical work". Source: Anecdata.

Answer (score -1):

There does not seem to be a single word derived from the word *electricity*, no doubt because electricity appeared late in the history of trades.  The first electrical device seems to have been the telegraph by Francis Ronalds in 1816, not much more than a hundred years ago.  Those were the times when engineering came to the for in all sorts of ways, and the profession of engineers.

Those who go into peoples homes to sort out or install electrical devices are generally called *electricians*.  They can also be referred to a *electrical engineers*.  The trade itself can be called *electrical engineering*.  It is, alas, two words, but surely two words are better than none?

Comment: That's *two* hundred years ago!

Comment: Today, the field of electrical engineering largely deals with things that have to do with electronics, which varies from semiconductors, lasers, cameras, radios, to mathematics like video compression and robot walking. If you want somebody to deal with electrical power, you'd generally specify it as a _power engineer_, who specializes in [_power engineering_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_engineering). If you asked an EE about home wiring or power lines, they'd wouldn't know much, because the detailed study of power systems for a degree hasn't been required for maybe 50+ years.

Answer (score -1):

One word which might fit is

#### Wiring

Of course there are features of electrical installation which are not purely related to fitting wires, but fitting wires certainly does take a significant fraction of the job. More to the point though, anyone else you're talking to will understand.

Comment: Wiring is not a  trade.